# Jquery datatables Plug-In , display "No data available in table" after Sorting/Filtering Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatables, runtime

I use `JSON` format for getting data from server to fill `DataTables` table. 
In Success part of `$().ajax` function , I checked and the response is getting back successfuly. 
this is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cj3tf4xp/12/) for my table :

The sample of Json file returning back from server is like this :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "__type": "TEST1.Campaign",
            "BookingID": 0,
            "CatalogueNumber": "IEM201343000007",
            "CampaignId": 34,
            "StartTime": "/Date(1438437600000)/",
            "EndTime": "/Date(1440079200000)/",
            "DurationPlayout": 3,
            "AdDuration": 5,
            "CampaignType": "facebook",
            "Stations": [
                "7mate.brisbane.au",
                "eleven.brisbane.au",
                "nine.brisbane.au"
            ],
            "Client_ID": 192,
            "ContactID": 5851,
            "AdvertiserID": 9228,
            "Active": true,
            "SModified": null,
            "DSP": "SiteScout",
            "ClientName": "",
            "AdvertiserName": "H A Consulting",
            "ContactName": "Aisling Bannan"
        }
    ] }
```

I'm creating the table manually after ajax response, so Is there any issue with datatables in this way? 
when I  filter or Sort the table records by a column , this issue happens:

---

> No data available in table

---

Any Help would be appreciated.

12/08/2015 **Updated Code:**

I updated the code in [this fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/cj3tf4xp/14/) based on *Gyrocode's* answer.
1)when I click refresh button, the table is initializing again,but it will be empty when I click sort columns or want to search data.
2)the width of each column is not set correctly.
3)some columns are hidden but they're shown in the table at the end of each row.
4)Also for using [Orthogonal data](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/orthogonal-data.html), I need to have datetime in MM/DD/YY, I used .Net datetime for this field , but it seems it changed to TimeStamp in JSON string at Client-side.so, is there any way to make it in custome format?

Comment: append data to table body not just to table.

Comment: There were a couple problems with your fiddle, but not sure if this is what's causing your issue or just a problem with the example code. First, the table ID is `example`, but it's called as `Items` in your JS. Change the ID of the table to `Items`. Second, in your JS, you have an extra `)}` after `return false`. Let me know if these are just fiddle errors or a problem with your code.

Comment: @jonmrich Thank you for informing me about issues . yes. they are fiddle errors which I fixed them.

Answer (score 2):

> **CAUSE**

There are many syntax errors and other issues with your code, this answer would be too long to list them all.

Important things to consider are:

- Need to use the correct number of `th` that includes the hidden columns as well. Use `columnDefs` later to hide certain columns.
- Your approach with generating `tr`/`td` is OK but makes the code complex. DataTables can send ajax request for you and will handle returned data for you with correct configuration. See [Orthogonal data example](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/orthogonal-data.html) for more information.

> **DEMO**

Please see [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cj3tf4xp/6/) for demonstration of corrected code.

Comment: thank you for your answer , and nice Fiddle. actually I had some typo issues in Fiddle but I updated it. as you mentioned, the problem was my datatables definition( as your code):

var table = $('#Items').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            { targets: [6,7,8,9,10], visible: false }
        ]
    });

Comment: I have a problem with this solution, actually , the table should be initialize at page load and fill on some texts changes, so should I initialize it on every text_change ? it gets error , and when I try to use http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3 , the footer will not work correctly

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem, otherwise it's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.