# Data Table hangs sporadically (No data available in table) when data sorted or loaded with Knockout binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, datatables

I am binding data to a table using `Knockout JS` and the [JQuery/Bootstrap based; Data Table API](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap-simple.html). The table becomes unresponsive sporadically when sorted or loaded. There are no errors in the log.

It also shows 0 of 0 data as illustrated in the screenshot below:

[image]

I have seen similar errors/issues but could not get a solutions for them, E.g. [This post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913802/jquery-datatables-plug-in-display-no-data-available-in-table-after-sorting-f)

*Code:*

```
    function viewModel(){

        var self = this;
        self.Data = ko.observableArray([]);

        $.getJSON('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all', function(data){
            self.Data(data);
        });
    }

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel());

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable();
    });
```

*HTML:*

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="example" cellspacing="0"  
class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Country</th>
                <th scope="col">Capital</th>
                <th scope="col">Population</th>
                <th scope="col">Region</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Country</th>
                <th scope="col">Capital</th>
                <th scope="col">Population</th>
                <th scope="col">Region</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: Data">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: capital"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: population"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: region"></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
        </div>
```

Here is a full [working example (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/z4zk9zdz/1/) utilizing a REST API so that the exact problem is accurately replicated:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your example may be with how you're dealing with your data when you get it back from the API call.

I've put together a quick example that achieves what I think you're trying to achieve and the sorting and searching work quickly for me.

When I get the JSON data back from the API, I use the Knockout arrayMap utility function to create an array of "Country" objects that have observable properties that I have mapped the JSON data to. I've bound the table to my observableArray of Country objects.

Initialising the data table in the same way you have works fine for me in this case.

The full working solution is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/eroIox6zqBFOVnf86Mdk?p=preview

**script.js**

```js
var ViewModel = function(jsonData) {
  var countries = ko.utils.arrayMap(jsonData, function(item) {
    return new Country(item)
  });
  this.Countries = ko.observableArray(countries);
};

var Country = function(jsonItem) {
  this.Name = ko.observable(jsonItem.name);
  this.Capital = ko.observable(jsonItem.capital);
  this.Population = ko.observable(jsonItem.population);
  this.Region = ko.observable(jsonItem.region);
};

window.onload = function() {
  $.getJSON('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all', function(data) {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
    $("#example").dataTable();
  });
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<table id="example" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Country</th>
      <th scope="col">Capital</th>
      <th scope="col">Population</th>
      <th scope="col">Region</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Country</th>
      <th scope="col">Capital</th>
      <th scope="col">Population</th>
      <th scope="col">Region</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Countries">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Capital"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Population"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Region"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks: I had given up and decided to create a sortable table based on another approach that was a knockout only solution, however, this is still very valid and extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are fairly slow to render within Knockout, and if your table is based on a `computed`, I could see how you could have some issues with redrawing time. But that's not happening here.

Apart from loading the data and binding it to the table rows, there's no data manipulation going on in your viewmodel. All the data manipulation is done by the dataTable plug-in, which you initialize with a single jQuery call. Properly, that should be done within a binding handler. You also need to know what is going on within the plug-in when it sorts, filters, or whatever it does, because you may need to mediate those changes back to your observableArray within your binding handler.

Bottom line: you need a binding handler for the dataTable. There may be one already written; I haven't Googled for it. Give that a try.